# How to pass a parameter to a custom action from the setup file in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield

I am trying to pass parameter to the custom action. The parameter is to be passed from InstallShield setup file:

```
setup.exe [PARAMETER_VALUE]
```

This `[PARAMETER_VALUE]` is to be consumed by the custom action executable. The custom action executable will behave accordingly based on this parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a Basic MSI project (since you reference custom actions), the supported way to pass in information on the command line is through Windows Installer Properties. Pass these as follows:

```
setup.exe /v"PARAMETER=Value"
```

Ensure the name of the property (PARAMETER in the example) includes no lowercase letters so that it is public, and consider listing it in the SecureCustomProperties property.